# How to create a view containing field of an associated model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, belongs-to, has-one

In my project, I have an `Organization` model and an `Address` model. Here is the association beetween the models:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :adresse
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :organization
end
```

I would like to know how to create a new form and include attributes from both model. For the moment, my organization/new.html.erb look like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: organization, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if organization.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(organization.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this organization from being saved:</h2>
     <ul>
       <% organization.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <li><%= message %></li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :organizationName%>
    <%= form.text_field :organizationName, id: :organization_organizationName %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, id: :organization_email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :website %>
    <%= form.text_field :website, id: :organization_website %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I tried to add this to the form but address method is not recognized:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :streetNumber %>
  <%= form.text_field :organization.address.streetNumber%>
</div>
```

In controller, I have access to the address of the organization like:

```
@organization.address.streetNumber
```

PS: I'm new to Rails ;)

Comment: This is an old discussion, but nobody commented on the obvious typo in the question. You list the `Organization` model twice and the `Adresse` model is missing. 

It would be logical that the Organization `has_one` Adresse (or even several), and Adresse `belongs_to` Organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) is for.

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  First name: <%= person_form.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= person_form.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= fields_for :permission, @person.permission do |permission_fields| %>
    Admin?  : <%= permission_fields.check_box :admin %>
  <% end %>

  <%= person_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do I include this in my actual form? Like below orgazisation fields?

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe: yep, `<%= fields_for :adresse, organization.adresse do |address_fields| %>` and so on

Comment: It's working but when I'm trying to create an organization, it says that address must exist.

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe: well, that's a bit out of scope of this question, isn't it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749519/how-to-save-a-model-containing-attributes-of-another-model-in-rails