# How to save a model containing attributes of another model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save, associations

In my project, I have an `Organization` model and an `Address` model. Here is the association beetween the models:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization
end
```

I added address attributes in my new organization form like this (form_with for `Organization` attributes and fields_for for `Address` attributes):

```
<%= form_with(model: organization, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :organizationName %>
    <%= form.text_field :organizationName, id: :organization_organizationName  %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, id: :organization_courriel %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :webSite %>
    <%= form.text_field :webSite, id: :organization_webSite %>
  </div>

  <%= fields_for :adresse, organization.address do |address_fields| %>
      Street number: <%=address_fields.text_field :streetNumber%><br>
      Street: <%=address_fields.text_field :street%><br>
      City: <%=address_fields.text_field :city%><br>
      Province: <%=address_fields.text_field :province%><br>
      Postal code: <%=address_fields.text_field :postalCode%><br>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I'm trying to save the orginization with his address, organization is saved but his address is not.

How do I save the address of the organization?

Here is my OrganizationController:

```
def new
    @organization = Organization.new
    @organization.build_address
end

def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    @organization.save
    //...
end

def organization_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:organizationName, :email, :webSite, address_attributes:[:streetNumber, :street, :city, :province, :postalCode])
end
```

## EDIT

The problem was my view. My form didn't include my field_for section.

Solution:

```
<%=form.field_for :address do |address_fields| %>
```

Comment: which version of rails you are using?

Comment: Rails version 5.1.4

Comment: You misspelled `ApplicationRecord`. It's `ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: @Cyzanfar: you haven't used rails 5, have you? :)

Comment: No not yet @SergioTulentsev! Amazing they made it even simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 belongs_to :address, optional: true
params.require(:organization).permit(:name,address_attributes: [:id,:city])
```

Comment: I want to be able to save the address each time with my organization. Address is not optional in my case.

Comment: Can you change it like Organization has on address and address belongs_to organization.?

Comment: I just did it and I think I'm on something here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863818/rails-one-form-to-two-models?rq=1

Comment: You are not permitting address attributes.

Comment: I changed my organization_params method in the controller but address is not saved. Same problem.

Comment: Just Do above two changes and every thing will be start working I Have tested address is also being saved with organization.

Comment: Do I need to add organization_id in address permitting attributes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156755/discussion-between-shoaib-and-emile-pettersen-coulombe).

Comment: No you wont need to require `organization_id` since you are building the association from the Oganization. As per the doc:http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. `build_association` method returns a new object of the associated type. This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes, and the link through this object's foreign key will be set, but the associated object will not yet be saved.